# Map the same url to ethernet ip and hotspot(wifi) ip on ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dns, dhcp

1. `Presentation of condition`: I create a gitlab server using docker on Linux. I can access gitlab via 127.0.0.1:8000 (docker 8000 port: host PC 80 port using http protocol) on **host PC**.
   The host PC has two network boards which have 10.42.0.50(hotspot,wifi) and 192.168.1.50(ethernet) IP.
2. `Ques`: I wanna use another PC in the same local network via wifi **or** wire network to access gitlab server in a web browser. Now I can access gitlab server on another PC via *192.168.1.50:8000* **or** *10.42.0.50:8000*. However, I wanna **unify the address through URL** when another PC in local network accesses the gitlab server. How can I **map the same URL to the two IP**: 192.168.1.50 and 10.42.0.50? If so, I can access gitlab server on different PC no matter which network connects.

Comment: Are you using a proper firewall for this setup, or a consumer-grade router? The easiest would be to allow traffic on port 8000 from 10.42.0.0/24 to 192.168.1.50 (I'd choose wired over wifi for stability). You can then access 192.168.1.50 from either subnet.

Comment: I need to access the gitlab server via both wired and wireless networks. I just build a DNS server to map all requests for a URL to IP of gitlab server (192.168.1.50 wired or 10.42.0.50 wireless). And How to build the DNS server?

Comment: Forget DNS just yet. You don't need it if you're using IP addresses instead of domain names. You need to route between two different subnets.

Comment: OK! Could you please give me some detailed docs or methods?

Comment: If I have routed between two different subnets, then how do I project a unified URL or IP to the 192.\** and 10.\** IP?

Comment: I think you're asking in the wrong forum, this is not a Ubuntu question. In my opinion, you need to: a) route between the subnets and maybe b) install a reverse proxy or load balancer to serve the content. I don't think DNS works the way you think it does.